# how to deploy quasar - vue application on gitlab ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, quasar-framework

I have a basic quasar page that is created using $ quasar create .
I want to deploy the application on Gitlab ci but the deplyment keeps giving me errors i have managed to fix the build and test errors but cant figure out the deployment part of it.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
build site:
  image: node:10
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install -g @quasar/cli
    - npm install --progress=false
    - quasar build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist

unit test:
  image: node:10
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false

deploy:
  image: alpine
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache rsync openssh
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - rsync -rav --delete dist/ user@server.com:/your/project/path/
```

[Error during deplyment phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP1Zn.png)

i tried adding `rsync -av -e "ssh -vv" --delete ...`
this is the error i get [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try and do your rsync with ssh verbose active, in order to see more about the error:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -vv" --delete ...
```

Check the [permission for your ssh elements](https://gist.github.com/grenade/6318301#file-ssh-key-permissions-sh).
For instance:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```